# Peak-Signal Noise Ratio

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to find out the peak-signal noise ratio(PSNR) of two images. I wrote the code in two different ways. The answer came out to be different.

```
% Read the image
I1 = imread('Image1.bmp');
I2 = imread('Image2.bmp');
```

Method1

```
P = 255;
MSE =0;
MSE = mean((I1(:)-I2(:)).^2);
PSNR = 10*log10(P^2/MSE);
```

Method 2

```
 I3 = 0;
    for i=1:512
        for j=1:512
            I3 = I3 + (I1(i,j)-I2(i,j))^2;
        end
    end

Sum = mean(I3);
Sum1 = 255^2/Sum;
PSNR = 10*log10(Sum1);
```

For Method 1,  i got a value of 30.1131 and for method 2, i got a value of 24.0654. I am not sure why the values are different. Need some help on it.

Comment: Your Method 1 is the idiomatic way of doing it in MATLAB. Although I've answered as to why you got a different value in the second case, I suggest using Method 1.

Answer (score 5):

In Method 2, `I3` is just a scalar and is the sum of the squared differences. Taking the `mean()` of a scalar will return the same value. The mistake is that you haven't normalized `I3` by the number of elements in the image. You should change the corresponding line in Method 2 to

```
Sum = I3/512^2;
```

and it should work correctly. More generally, it should be

```
Sum = I3/prod(size(I1));
```